# Анимация на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Не работает анимация на JS, пытался сделать, чтобы при нажатии стрелки вправо шла анимация пофайлово, но ни чего не происходит

```js
var rabbit = {
  obj: document.getElementsByClassName('img')
  frame: var frames = ["'url(../pic/rabbit/zero.png) no-repeat'", "'url(../pic/rabbit/first.png) no-repeat'", "'url(../pic/rabbit/second.png) no-repeat'", "'url(../pic/rabbit/third.png) no-repeat'", "'url(../pic/rabbit/rourth.png) no-repeat'", "'url(../pic/rabbit/fifth.png) no-repeat'"]
  run: run() {
    if (event.keyCode == 39) {
      var j = 0;
      while (j != 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < frames.Length; i++) {
          var std = document.getElementsByClassName('img');
          std.style.background = frames[i];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.fullScreen {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.img {
  height: 600px;
  width: 310px;
  background: url(../pic/rabbit/zero.png) no-repeat;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullScreen" onkeypress="run()">
  <div class="img">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Событие `onkeypress` вешать на `div` не верное решение...

```js
var img = document.querySelector('.img');
var foto = [
  'http://via.placeholder.com/420x240/ff9900/0000ff?text=Foto-1',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/420x240/ff9900/0000ff?text=Foto-2',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/420x240/ff9900/0000ff?text=Foto-3',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/420x240/ff9900/0000ff?text=Foto-4',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/420x240/ff9900/0000ff?text=Foto-5',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/420x240/ff9900/0000ff?text=Foto-6'
];
var count = 0;

document.onkeydown = function(event) {

  if (event.key === 'ArrowRight') {
    if (count < foto.length - 1) {
      count++;
      img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + foto[count] + ')';
    } else {
      return false
    }

  } else if (event.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
    if (count != 0) {
      count--;
      img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + foto[count] + ')';
    } else {
      return false
    }
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #404040;
}

.fullScreen {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.img {
  height: 240px;
  width: 420px;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/420x240/ff9900/0000ff?text=Foto-1);
  margin: auto;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullScreen">
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: _Событие onkeypress вешать на div не верное решение_ - почему же?

Comment: ну, кнопки клавы разве будут на это реагировать? не проверял не должнв

Comment: событие всплывающее, следовательно, если внутри дива будут лежать  элементы в которых это событие происходит, обработчик сработает. Примерно по этому принципу работает и твой вариант, просто путь от элемента на котором произошло события до обработчика больше

Comment: с именами беда: что за `a`, что за `b`? `b` в принципе вообще не нужна, потому что есть `.length`

Comment: @Grundy, понятно, и еще и скажи почему в моем варианте, если прокрутить все фото до конца, то обратно не сразу листает?

Comment: Потому что условия неверно поставил. выведи себе куда-нибудь значение твоей переменной `a` и посмотри что с ней происходит в этом случае

Comment: @Grundy в консль вывел, и там было верно, не поверишь.... вот в чем ворос, я всегда проверяю, не делаю в слепую

Comment: изменения `a` происходят после присваивания, поэтому в граничных случаях  нужно два клика